# Loop for custom-post-type comparing taxonomy terms for "related" posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wp-query, loop

I have a custom-post-type named `my_projects` and a custom-taxonomy called `project_tags`.

I want to write a function that is returning 5 posts of this post-type based on a given taxonomy term.

So I want to call `<?php get_related_projects("Car"); ?>` and get 5 posts that also share the `tag` car returned.

**This is my current attempt (that doesn't work)**

```
function get_related_projects( $term ) {
    echo '<ul class="featured-items">';

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => array('my_project'),
        'order' => 'DSC',
        'post_count' => 5,
        'meta_key' => 'project_tags',
        'meta_compare'   => $term,
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        global $post;
        ?>
        <li>
            <figure class="project-image">
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                   </a>
                 <?php endif; ?>
            </figure>
            <h1 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><span class="goto">a</span> <?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        </li>
        <?php
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Since I'm not an expert when it comes to custom loops I wonder what I'm doing wrong here? Thank you for your help.

**UPDATE:**

```
<?php if ( get_related_projects( "Car" ) ):  ?>
        <em>Related Projects</em>
        <?php get_related_projects("Car"); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `$args` array a little bit:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'my_projects' ), // it need to get the posts from this post_type
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'project_tags' => $term // search taxonomy
);
```

Other ways to search for taxonomy terms can be found [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) in the WordPress Codex pages.

Answer on your **update**:

You can add checks that return `false` when the function "can't" return values:

```
// if the given category doesn't exist
if ( ! is_category( $term ) )
    return false;

// if the given category doen't have posts
if ( ! $loop->have_posts() )
    return false;
```

The way you set up your code to check if there are related projects will not work the way you set up the function now, try this:

```
function get_related_projects( $term ) {
    // if the given category doesn't exist
    if ( ! is_category( $term ) )
        return false;

    $return = '';
    $return .= '<ul class="featured-items">';

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => array( 'my_projects' ), // it need to get the posts from this post_type
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'project_tags' => $term // search taxonomy
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    // if the given category doen't have posts
    if ( ! $loop->have_posts() )
        return false;

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        global $post;

        $figure = '';
        if ( has_post_thumbnail()) :
            $figure = sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s">%3$s</a>',
                get_permalink( get_the_ID() ),
                the_title_attribute( array( 'echo' => false ) ),
                get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID() )
            );
        endif;

        $return .= sprintf( '
            <li>
                <figure class="project-image">%1$s</figure>
                <h1 class="title"><a href="%2$s"><span class="goto">a</span> %3$s</a></h1>
            </li>',
            $figure,
            get_permalink( get_the_ID() ),
            get_the_title()
        );
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();
    $return .= '</ul>'

    return $return;
}
```

And then use the following code to check the function:

```
<?php if ( $projects = get_related_projects( "Car" ) ):  ?>
    <em>Related Projects</em>
    <?php echo $projects; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, perfect. One more question. Is it possible to rewrite the function so, that I have an if-statement in there that returns `false` if no posts where matched? So I want to use the function in a second different manner. See my update in the question. -> So I don't want to print the section "Related Projects" if there are no projects matched.

Comment: I edited my answer for you :-)

Comment: Wow, thank you. Exactly what I needed. In this case I ask even for the last thing I'd like to have. Is it also possible to not only return the "last" 5 posts, but a random set of the posts. So I want 5 related projects, but not simply the latest ones but a random set.

Comment: Just add `'orderby' => 'rand'` in your `$args` array and remove `'order' => 'DESC'` ;-)